# Declaring property names as string constant is good approach?

Tags: java

I am working on project , where i was told to declare all string as constant and fetch from there . I want to understand need behind this.

Comment: Depends on the project.

Comment: Please include more details in your question. The answer to question is subjective and depends on the type of project you are working on.

Comment: Too vague but if those strings are just text strings and are not used as "logic" it would be the first step in setting up internationalization.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "no magic constants" guideline: don't just insert constants into the code directly, because they look like unexplained "magic". Also it helps avoid typos if you are using the same constant multiple times.

However if the name of the constant is the same as the contents of the string (modulo formatting and spaces), it's missing the point and it's pointless, in my view.

Also if the string is clearly a prompt to the user, it's *not* unexplained magic, so this guideline is totally inapplicable and shouldn't be applied in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If the String constant is used in more than one place, and the correct functioning of the program requires this, it is better to use a constant, eg

```
public static final String ONE = "apple";

// client usage
doSomething(ONE);

// service usage
void doSomething(String action) {
    if (action.equals(ONE)) {
        // whatever
    else ...
}
```

Without a constant, you get "Stringly typed" code, because you can pass around rubbish and the code will compile:

```
doSomething("foo"); // compiles, but won't function correctly
```

However, using Strings as meaningful constants is still "loose" code. It's better to use a enum:

```
enum Action {
    ONE, TWO, THREE
}

void doSomething(Action action) {
    if (action == ONE) {
        // whatever
    else ..
```

Now the compiler will enforce that only valid constants are passed around.

For non-reused String constants, I wouldn't bother unless it made sense. No dogmatic rule should be blindly followed. Do it if it makes sense.

Comment: Would you mind choosing a different name in the example? I know it's just an example, but we don't want people to think it's a good idea to declare a constant named `ONE` with the value of `"one"`. It defeats both purposes of declaring constants: It doesn't make the usage clearer(`ONE` does not convey any more meaning than `"1"`), and it doesn't aid when you want to change the value globally(you either end up with `public static final String ONE = "2";`, or [you have to hunt down every occurrence of `ONE` and change it to `TWO`](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/95))

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb: if you can think of a name that can describe the constant(in the context of it's usage) better than the literal itself - declare a global constant. If you can't - use the literal.

For example: if you have `System.out.println("Hello")`, it's pretty hard to find a better name for the string literal - `HELLO`? `HELLO_STRING`? `TEXT_THAT_SAYS_HELLO`? those things don't add much value, so we are better off using the literal directly. However, if we add some context - for example, that `"hello"` is the general way of the application to greet the user before displaying stuff to them - we suddenly have a better name for this constant - `GENERAL_GREETING`. Also note that the very same fact that gave us the name makes it more beneficial to use a global constant - since it's the general greeting used everywhere, it makes sense to define it as a global constant so we can easily change it across the application.

Answer (score 0):

- It eliminates multiple uses of the same string literals strewn across your project, necessitating wide-scale, often difficult-to-find usages.
- It provides known, documented variables for the same, e.g., instead of having to manually document the string "foo.bar" you provide Javadocs for the constant FOO_BAR.
- It eliminates some types of minor bugs, e.g., minor misspellings.
- It drives the usage of resource and/or configuration files for user-visible strings, e.g., prompts and messages: this should be preferred to string constants under many, but not all, circumstances. E.g., for a tiny little project the overhead of a resource file may not make sense–and you'd probably still need constants to define the resource names.

Whether or not it makes sense to constantize *all* string values is impossible to answer in the general sense.

Answer (score 0):

- To avoid duplication:
  Its a good idea to use constants when you have at least two identical values with the same visibility. eg inside same class.
- To write semantic code:
  Its not the same

  ```
  int totalPrize = product.getPrize() * 1.21f;
  ```

  than:

  ```
  int totalPrize = product.getPrize() * VAT;
  ```
- To expose values to other clases:

  ```
  if(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION == response)
  ```

Comment: the question was about *String* constants